# How do I solve Splash screen/Form issue of this nature in Java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, screen, splash-screen

The program tells me:

```
Invalid target release:1.8
```

when I run it.

When I pace the mouse on the underlined error line it says:

```
Lambda expression not expected here
```

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce the error.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.